Jenkins second parameter is not refreshed on the first load
I have a jenkinsfile with 3 parameters to deploy an artifact to an environment.
properties([parameters([
  choice(name: 'ENVIRONNEMENT', choices: ['dev', 'test', 'pprod', 'prod']'),
  [
    $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
    name: 'MAVEN_TYPE',
    choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
    filterLength: 1,
    filterable: false,
    referencedParameters: 'ENVIRONNEMENT',
    script: [
      $class: 'GroovyScript',
      script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: ('''return (ENVIRONNEMENT.equals('prod') || ENVIRONNEMENT.equals('pprod')) ? ['releases'] : ['releases', 'snapshots']''')]
    ]
  ],
  [
    $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
    name: 'VERSION',
    choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
    description: 'Version to deploy',
    filterLength: 1,
    filterable: false,
    referencedParameters: 'MAVEN_TYPE',
    script: [
      $class: 'GroovyScript',
      script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: ('''import javax.xml.parsers.*
        import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
        import hudson.util.Secret
        def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class, hudson.security.ACL.SYSTEM);
        def cred = creds.find { it.id == 'jenkins-nexus-user' }
        def authString = "${cred.username}:${Secret.toString(cred.password)}".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()
        def connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://nexus.url/repository/maven-${MAVEN_TYPE}/com/company/project/maven-metadata.xml").openConnection()
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic ${authString}")
        if (connection.responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
          def response = new XmlSlurper().parse(connection.inputStream)
          def versions = response.versioning.versions.version.collect { it.toString() }
          return versions.reverse().take(5)
        }''')],
        fallbackScript: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: ('''return ["Error retreiving versions"]''')]
      ]
    ]
  ])])
  pipeline { [... skipped ...] }

The 3 parameters ENVIRONNEMENT, MAVEN_TYPE and VERSION uses one another. VERSION needs MAVEN_TYPE and MAVEN_TYPE needs ENVIRONEMENT.
When I choose an environment, the MAVEN_TYPE gets updated and VERSION also. If I change the MAVEN_TYPE, the VERSION is updated.
The problems is on the first load of the form. The ENVIRONNEMENT parameter is set to the default value which is the first of the combo. But the MAVEN_TYPE parameter appears with a spinning disc, and you can't change its value. If you want to deploy to the first environment, you have to change to the second value, let the parameters refresh themselves and choose back the first value of the combo, it's very annoying.
I tried changing the script of the second parameter to include a default value of the first parameter, something like that
def env = ENVIRONNEMENT ?: 'dev'
return (env.equals('prod') || env.equals('pprod')) ? ['releases'] : ['releases', 'snapshots']

But it still does not work.
This happens on Jenkins v2.479.2 with Active Choices plugin v2.8.6
I have parameters like these working on an older Jenkins v2.303.2 with Active Choices plugin v2.5.6 (I'm currently upgrading my pipelines to the new server)
Fun fact, if I remove the third parameter, the second behave as it should, it is set correctly on the first load without the spinning disc.
How can I force the second parameter to behave correctly ?

Did you try to turn your first parameter into ActiveChoice instead of regular choice?

Thanks MaratC, it works, post it as an answer so i can mark it as answered !
